# Sequoia 2000 Benchmark data?

Tags: data, benchmark

In reading about DBSCAN clustering it mentions the SEQUOIA 2000 Benchmark database was used for benchmarking.  Is this data set available anywhere?  Or, is there another set like it?

So far my searching hasn't turned up anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try this link http://s2k-ftp.cs.berkeley.edu/sequoia/benchmark/

I think that is the right resource.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried here [Found this, any good?](https://asc.llnl.gov/sequoia/benchmarks/)